# How to delete coordinate system from raster file with prj.adf?

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

How can I delete the coordinate system from a raster file like .adf which is multiple files?

I found a file with tha name "prj.adf" so if I delete this file is it enough?

In shapefiles usually Ι delete the .prj file and thene I define the projection again, if necessary.

Comment: You can follow these steps to define or modify the raster coordinate system: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000002m000000

Answer (score 1):

This data is in **[Esri Grid format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000w000000)** and I would not advise deleting its prj.adf file because that may be referenced elsewhere in its binary structure.

As @Craig said you should instead use the help instructions for **[Defining or modifying a raster's coordinate system](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000002m000000)**.